# Removing Null Values returned by subquery in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove the null values of the result set. I am using a subquery for my columns. I am unable to remove null values using the having function.

I am using the query below,

```
Select 
    MONTH(Salesdate) as Month, 
    (Select sum(InvoiceSale) where year(SalesDate) = 2013) as SalesVal2013 
from 
    tblSales
Where 
    tblsales.InvoiceSale is not NUll
group by 
    Month(SalesDate)
Having 
    sum(InvoiceSale) is not null
```

Any direction towards the solution will be very helpful.

Thank you

Phil

Comment: The subquery is missing a `from (tablename)` clause.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason for the subquery that I can see. Try this instead:

```
SELECT MONTH(Salesdate) AS Month, SUM(InvoiceSale) AS SalesVal2013 
FROM tblSales
WHERE tblsales.InvoiceSale IS NOT NUll
AND year(SalesDate)=2013
AND InvoiceSale IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(SalesDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the test for null in the in the sub-select, not in the HAVING clause, as here:

```
Select MONTH(Salesdate) as Month, (Select sum(InvoiceSale) where year(SalesDate)=2013 AND InvoiceSale IS NOT NULL) as SalesVal2013 from tblSales
group by Month(SalesDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the same thing in the `HAVING` as in the actual computation for SalesVal2013

This works..

I made up some sample data. Try this out

```
With SalesList as 
(
          Select '1/1/2013' SalesDate, 123 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '1/1/2014' SalesDate, 123 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '2/1/2013' SalesDate,  NULL InvoiceSale
    Union Select '3/1/2013' SalesDate, 234 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '3/1/2012' SalesDate, 234 InvoiceSale
)
Select SalesDate, (Select Sum (InvoiceSale) Where Year(SalesDate)=2013) SalesVal2013
FROM SalesList 
Group by SalesDate
Having ((Select Sum (InvoiceSale) Where Year(SalesDate)=2013)) Is Not NULL
```

Here is the output

```
SalesDate SalesVal2013
--------- ------------
1/1/2013  123
3/1/2013  234

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT**

However, I see you are including MONTH (SalesDate) in the clause, which throws a big wrench in the works.  Does this rewrite work for you?

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

With SalesList as 
(
          Select '1/1/2013' SalesDate, 123 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '1/1/2014' SalesDate, 123 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '2/1/2013' SalesDate,  NULL InvoiceSale
    Union Select '3/1/2013' SalesDate, 435 InvoiceSale
    Union Select '3/1/2013' SalesDate, NULL InvoiceSale
    Union Select '3/1/2012' SalesDate, 234 InvoiceSale
)
Select Month (SalesDate), Sum (InvoiceSale)
FROM SalesList 
Where year(SalesDate)=2013
Group by Month (SalesDate)
Having Sum (InvoiceSale) Is Not NULL
```

OUTPUT

```
----------- -----------
1           123
3           435

(2 row(s) affected)
```